# Apache Camel, IBM MQ integration

Tags: java, apache-camel, jms, ibm-mq

I want to use Apache Camel to send a message on IBM MQ and so I wrote a simple program, but I am getting error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.camel.NoSuchEndpointException: No endpoint could be found for: queuename, please check your classpath contains the needed Camel component jar.
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.resolveMandatoryEndpoint(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:499)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.sendBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:167)
```

My code:

```
CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();

//added that line after some checks but didnt help
context.addComponent("http", new HttpComponent());

 context.addComponent("test-jms",connFactory);

ProducerTemplate template = context.createProducerTemplate();

context.start();

template.sendBody("testQueueName", "Test  Message ");
```

`testQueueName` holds `queuename`.

I have all necessary dependencies in my `pom.xml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument of sendBody() must be an Apache Camel Endpoint, for example "activemq:MyQueue". In other words, it must be one of these: http://camel.apache.org/uris.html

If you configured IBM MQ as your JMS provider, I guess this should work:

```
template.sendBody("jms:queue:testQueueName", "Test  Message ");
```